# Updating ID based on views

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I have the following block of code.

```
<?php 
$count = get_tptn_post_count_only($POST_ID);
$rating_class = 'hot3';
        if( $count >= 0 && $count <= 3 )
{
$rating_class = 'hot3';
}
        elseif( $count > 4 && $count <= 10 )
{
    $rating_class = 'hot2';
}
        elseif( $count > 11 && $count <= 20 )
{
    $rating_class = 'hot1';
}
        elseif( $count > 5000 )
{
    $rating_class = 'hot1';
} 
?>
```

Now what I am trying to do is track the views on my post and then if their over the number provided update the image on my index page accordingly how ever it does not seem to work for anything other then the `hot3` portion which is the first tier.

I am currently basing all of the view tracking off of a plugin called [Top 10](https://wordpress.org/plugins/top-10/). 
If you're interested in seeing my entire loop you can do so [here](http://codepad.org/NqEOTAFB).

EDIT: [Plugin Settings](http://codepad.org/EikZpIY9).

also `$totalcntaccess = get_tptn_post_count_only( $id, 'total', $blog_id );` inside of the file [counter.php](http://codepad.org/NgMEBym8) <-- another fiddle link.

Comment: What's the value of `$count`?

Comment: to start you're missing the following values; 4,11, 21-5000. Secondly have you echoed `$count` to see what the function actually returns?

Comment: @davejal @snowdev `$count` returns 0 by default every time

Comment: so you have to check your function first! The problem is in your function to fetch the `$count`. If you need help with that, you should post the relevant code (the function that is called), but to test the other parts of your script you could give the count variable a value statically and try to see if the other code works as expected.

Comment: if `$count` is always zero, then it makes sense that `$rating_class` would always be set to "hot3". I'm unclear on the problem.

Comment: @showdev @Davejal Hum, now I am confused also because since creating this post I've learned a bit about my code that I didn't know before. My only assumption is that `get_tptn_post_count_only($POST_ID);` is not the function to return the actual post view count.

Comment: @davejal I updated post please check out the fiddle I posted containing the Plugin Settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix without using the plugin above and using a tool that I found on some blog but with a similar method.

**Functions.php** ([Source](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/))

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Set this in the index of your **Single.php** file.

```
<?php
      setPostViews(get_the_ID());
?>
```

Then on your index loop make it this.

```
<?php 

$count = getPostViews(get_the_ID());
    $rating_class = 'hot3';
        if( $count >= 0 && $count <= 1000 )
{
    $rating_class = 'hot3';
}
        elseif( $count > 1000 && $count <= 2500 )
{
    $rating_class = 'hot2';
}
        elseif( $count > 2500 && $count <= 5000 )
{
    $rating_class = 'hot1';
}
        elseif( $count > 5000 )
{
    $rating_class = 'hot1';
} 
print $count;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure of what are you trying to do. I'm not even familiar with Wordpress (and I think that is what you ar using). But I found some possible errors on your code:

You have thing like `if( $count >= 0 && $count <= 3 )` and then `elseif( $count > 4 && $count <= 10 )`. In this case the number `4` will not be a valid number. Yu have to use `$count >= 4` or `$count > 3`. The same error is valid for numbers `11` and in the range `21-5000`.

Hope this help.